# loop through and match one dataframe to another with a lookup column taking a unique row each time (in terms of value in another column)

Tags: r, loops, join, merge, match

I don't know if I am searching the question incorrectly, as it's a tricky one to explain, but I haven't found any answers online thus far! Basically I have two dataframes, DF1 has 120 rows, and DF2 has 22000 rows. They both have a "lookup" column, based on values from three other columns. They look something like this (a subset):

DF1:

| Lookup |
| --- |
| EM1PRI |
| EM1PRI |
| EM2PRI |
| EM3PRI |
| EM3PRI |

DF2:

| Lookup | ID |
| --- | --- |
| EM1PRI | 14567 |
| EM1PRI | 12345 |
| EM1PRI | 13456 |
| EM1PRI | 15678 |
| EM2PRI | 16789 |
| WM1PRI | 17890 |

I want to take the ID from DF2 for each available match to the lookup column in DF1, looping through without replacement so each ID is unique. If there are none available then it needs to be NA. This is how I want the output to look:

DF3:

| Lookup | ID |
| --- | --- |
| EM1PRI | 14567 |
| EM1PRI | 12345 |
| EM2PRI | 16789 |
| EM3PRI | NA |
| EM3PRI | NA |

I don't know if this is a loop or a match or a merge, or all three. Very grateful for any advice!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use row numbers for each `Lookup` value in both data.frames, then join on both the `Lookup` value as well as the row number.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Lookup) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% 
              group_by(Lookup) %>%
              mutate(rn = row_number())) %>%
  dplyr::select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
  Lookup    ID
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 EM1PRI 14567
2 EM1PRI 12345
3 EM2PRI 16789
4 EM3PRI    NA
5 EM3PRI    NA
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Lookup = c("EM1PRI", "EM1PRI", "EM2PRI", "EM3PRI", 
"EM3PRI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Lookup = c("EM1PRI", "EM1PRI", "EM1PRI", "EM1PRI", 
"EM2PRI", "WM1PRI"), ID = c(14567, 12345, 13456, 15678, 16789, 
17890)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```